# Alternatives to using RFile in Symbian

Tags: serialization, file-io, symbian

This question is in continuation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011272/problem-in-calling-a-virtual-function-across-symbian-dlls) related to File I/O.

I am using RFile to open a file and read/write data to it. Now, my requirement is such that I would have to modify certain fields within the file. I separate each field within a record with a colon and each record with a newline. Sample is below:

```
abc@def.com:Albert:1:2
def@ghi.com:Alice:3:1
```

Suppose I want to replace the '3' in the second record by '2'. I am finding it difficult to overwrite specific field in the file using RFile because RFile does not provide its users with such facility.

Due to this, to modify a record I have to delete the contents of the file and serialize ( that is loop through in memory representation of records and write to the file ). Doing this everytime there is a change in a record's value is quite expensive as there are hundreds of records and the change could be quite frequent.

I searched around for alternatives and found [CPermanentFileStore.](http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Streams_And_Stores_%28Fundamentals_of_Symbian_C%2B%2B%29#CDirectFileStore_and_CPermanentFileStore) But I feel the API is hard to use as I am not able to find any source on the Internet that demonstrates its use.

Is there a way around this. Please help.

Comment: you want the file to remain readable by humans, don't you? any chance the vCard format would help?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version(s) of Symbian OS you are targetting, you could store the information in a relational database.  Since v9.4, Symbian OS includes an SQL implementation (based on the open source [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) engine).

Comment: DBMS is the name of the database engine in previous versions of Symbian OS.

Answer (score 1):

Using normal files for this type of records takes a lot of effort no matter the operating system. To be able to do this efficiently you need to reserve space in the file for expansion of each record - otherwise you need to rewrite the entire file if a record value changes from say 9 to 10. Also storing a lookup table in the file will make it possible to jump directly to a record using RFile::Seek.

The CPermamanentFileStore simplifies the actual reading and writing of the file but basically does what you have to do yourself otherwise. A database may be a better choice in this instance. If you don't want to use a database I think using stores would be be a better solution.